# Heap Implementation in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap

**What is a heap?**

A Heap is a special Tree-based data structure in which the tree is a complete binary tree. Generally, Heaps can be of two types:

**Max-Heap:** In a Max-Heap the key present at the root node must be greatest among the keys present at all of it’s children. The same property must be recursively true for all sub-trees in that Binary Tree.

**Min-Heap:** In a Min-Heap the key present at the root node must be minimum among the keys present at all of it’s children. The same property must be recursively true for all sub-trees in that Binary Tree.

**My code:**

```
class Heap:
    def __init__(self,type1 = False):
        self.type1 = type1
        self.array = []
        self.array.append(-1)

    def comparePush(self,parentIndex,currIndex):
        if self.type1 is False:
            return self.array[parentIndex] > self.array[currIndex]  # this is for minHeap
        else:
            return self.array[parentIndex] < self.array[currIndex]  # this is for maxHeap

    def push(self,item):
        self.array.append(item)
        currIndex = len(self.array)-1
        parentIndex = currIndex // 2

        
        while currIndex != 1 and self.comparePush(parentIndex,currIndex):
            # swapping elements
            temp = self.array[currIndex]
            self.array[currIndex] = self.array[parentIndex]
            self.array[parentIndex] = temp

            #changing the indices
            currIndex = parentIndex
            parentIndex = currIndex // 2

    def compareHeapify(self,childIndex,newIndex):
        if self.type1 is False: #minHeap check for minindex
            return self.array[childIndex] < self.array[newIndex]
        else:
            return self.array[childIndex] > self.array[newIndex]

    def heapify(self,currIndex):
        newIndex = currIndex
        last = len(self.array) - 1
        left = 2*newIndex
        right = 2*newIndex+1

        if left <= last and self.compareHeapify(left,newIndex):
            newIndex = left
        if right <= last and self.compareHeapify(right,newIndex):
            newIndex = right

        if newIndex!=currIndex:
            #swap
            temp = self.array[newIndex]
            self.array[newIndex] = self.array[currIndex]
            self.array[currIndex] = temp

            self.heapify(newIndex)

    def pop(self): # pops the max element in maxHeap and min element in minHeap44
        # swap item at index 1 with item at the last idex
        lastIndex = len(self.array) - 1
        temp = self.array[1]
        self.array[1] = self.array[lastIndex]
        self.array[lastIndex] = temp

        # pop element at the last index
        self.array.pop()

        #heapify
        self.heapify(1)

# q3 = Heap()
# q3.push(35)
# q3.push(33)
# q3.push(42)
# q3.push(10)
# q3.push(14)
# q3.push(19)
# q3.push(27)
# q3.push(44)
# q3.push(26)
# q3.push(31)
# print(q3.array)
# q3.pop()
# print(q3.array)

q3 = Heap()
q3.push(0)
q3.push(1)
q3.push(3)
q3.push(17)
q3.push(21)
q3.push(36)
q3.push(7)
q3.push(25)
q3.push(100)
q3.push(19)
print(q3.array)
```

**Current output:**

```
[-1, 0, 1, 3, 17, 19, 36, 7, 25, 100, 21]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[-1,0,1,3,17,21,36,7,25,100,19]
```

**What I think:**

According to me the push operation must be wrong however the logic seems to be perfectly fine which is confusing me. Also the array must be like level order traversal which is totally not true according to my output. How should I fix this? **Note:** Only 19 and 21 are off their correct postion or index.

Comment: I can't see anywhere where `type1` gets changed from `False`..

Comment: its because I am making a min heap right, if i did `q3 = Heap(True)` then a max heap would be generated. Note type1 is False by default and if no argument is supplied then it would default to min heap.

Comment: You might find more luck by comparing `if not self.type1:` as opposed to using `is` for comparisons but can't say for sure

Comment: Python has a `heapq` module. If this is homework, then see https://www.educative.io/edpresso/heap-implementation-in-python

Comment: What is confusing you? According to definition you placed here all is working totally fine. why you expect that result? both are right

Comment: 19 and 21 are at swapped indices. Is that alright?

Comment: yes it is alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I feel by looking at your code and the input is that your current output is right and your expected output is wrong actually.

The thorough explanation is as such:

Initially, we push 0 so the heap is having 0 only at the top.

We push 1, heap becomes something like this:

1. ```
        0
      /
     1
   ```

similarly if we follow all steps, the heap in each step is going to be like this: (See below for each step)

2. ```
           0
         /   \
        1     3
   ```
3. ```
           0
         /   \
        1     3
       /
      17
   ```
4. ```
           0
         /   \
        1     3
       / \
      17  21
   ```
5. ```
           0
         /   \
        1     3
       / \   /
      17 21 36
   ```
6. ```
           0
         /   \
        1     3
       / \   / \
      17 21 36  7
   ```
7. ```
           0
         /   \
        1     3
       / \   / \
      17 21 36  7
     /
    25
   ```
8. ```
           0
         /   \
        1     3
       / \   / \
      17 21 36  7
     / \
    25  100
   ```
9. ```
             0
           /   \
          /     \
         1        3
       /   \     /  \
      /     \   /    \
     17     21 36     7
    / \     /
   25 100  19
   ```

Now at this point, 19's parent is greater so, we swap it with 21.
Hence the correct heap would be something like this:

```
             0
           /   \
          /     \
         1        3
       /   \     /  \
      /     \   /    \
     17     19 36     7
    / \     /
   25 100  21
```

Now if we you do the level order traversal you will get the correct output as your current output.

**I think the expected output is correct for input "2" instead of "21" and may be this is where your confusion begins**